# CQ5 modify event fired on page delete

Tags: aem

I'm trying to use CQ5 workflow to control my resources (page in particular). 
I want to start different scripts on different events (Add/Delete/Modify). I have registered a launcher on each event.
When I delete a page anyway both the delete and modify events get fired and so both the script run. I can't understand how to exclude the modify event on delete.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: You can add the code to your question, so that we would be able to identify the actual issue and find a solution

Comment: I'm using workflow so I'm not working at code level. Anyway your answer has been quite useful thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When deleting a page, a version of the page is created before it is actually deleted. Which means it would actually fire a PageModification Event with [ModificationType](http://dev.day.com/content/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/PageModification.ModificationType.html) as `VERSION_CREATED`.

You can verify the same using the following Sample EventHandler which would just log the PageModifications.

```
@Component
@Service
@Property(name="event.topics", value=PageEvent.EVENT_TOPIC)
public class MyPageEventHandler implements EventHandler {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        PageEvent pgEvent = PageEvent.fromEvent(event);
        Iterator<PageModification> modifications = pgEvent.getModifications();

        while(modifications.hasNext()) {
            log.info("Page Modifications are {}", modifications.next().getType());
        }
    }
}
```